# Skaffold dev just hangs with first deploy message failure

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold

I am adding a NextJS frontend to my Kubernetes cluster. I added the following file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: client-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: client
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: client
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: client
          image: ldco2016/client
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: client
  ports:
    - name: client
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

to my `infra/k8s/` directory and then reconfigured `ingress-srv.yml` like so:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ticketing.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/users/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: auth-srv
              servicePort: 3000
          - path: /?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: client-srv
              servicePort: 3000
```

and the `skaffold.yml` file:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s*
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: ldco2016/auth
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: "src/**/*.ts"
            dest: .
    - image: ldco2016/client
      context: client
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: "**/*.js"
            dest: .
```

When I run `skaffold dev` it hangs about here:

```
starting deploy...
 - deployment.apps/auth-depl created
 - service/auth-srv created
 - deployment.apps/auth-mongo-depl created
 - service/auth-mongo-srv created
 - deployment.apps/client-depl created
 - service/client-srv created
 - ingress.extensions/ingress-service created
Waiting for deployments to stabilize...
 - deployment/auth-depl: waiting for rollout to finish: 0 of 1 updated replicas are available...
 - deployment/auth-mongo-depl: waiting for rollout to finish: 0 of 1 updated replicas are available...
 - deployment/client-depl: waiting for rollout to finish: 0 of 1 updated replicas are available...
 - deployment/client-depl is ready. [2/3 deployment(s) still pending]
 - deployment/auth-mongo-depl is ready. [1/3 deployment(s) still pending]
```

Any ideas?

I am running Docker desktop and Kubernetes as well. As this is a microservices application, I thought perhaps Kubernetes needed more resources. I tried to add more resources, but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: It is waiting for a few Deployments to be ready. What is the status for those "still pending" Deployments in the cluster? Is it problem with the Deployment or with Skaffold?

Comment: @Jonas, I believe the problem may be with Skaffold because I get this error: `exiting dev mode because first deploy failed: 1/3 deployment(s) failed`

Comment: @Jonas, I tried increasing resources, but did not help.

Comment: Skaffold's status-checks suppresses the logs until the system state stabilizes.  You can try `skaffold dev --status-check=false` to disable the status checks and see the logs in real-time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspected the issue was with one of my pods so I ran:  `kubectl get pods`

```
NAME                               READY   STATUS                       RESTARTS   AGE
auth-depl-5867ffb6bd-n5s6w         0/1     CreateContainerConfigError   0          2m7s
auth-depl-669fc8fd66-qr8kj         0/1     CreateContainerConfigError   0          6m11s
auth-mongo-depl-585f5f978c-tnc9w   1/1     Running                      0          2m7s
```

So the issue seemed to be with my `auth-depl` and so I reviewed its `yaml` file and I suspected the problem to be the secret key I added so I commented it out like so:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: ldco2016/auth
          # env:
          #   - name: JWT_KEY
          #     valueFrom:
          #       secretKeyRef:
          #         name: jwt-secret
          #         key: JWT_KEY
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth
  ports:
    - name: auth
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

To which then I ran `skaffold dev --cleanup=false` and saw:

```
Listing files to watch...
 - ldco2016/auth
Generating tags...
 - ldco2016/auth -> ldco2016/auth:latest
Some taggers failed. Rerun with -vdebug for errors.
Checking cache...
 - ldco2016/auth: Found Locally
Tags used in deployment:
 - ldco2016/auth -> ldco2016/auth:367e6b2171c5c8477a3f3458d23dd73030f35716df45a290aa54baa5f4dcdaa1
Starting deploy...
 - deployment.apps/auth-depl configured
 - service/auth-srv configured
 - deployment.apps/auth-mongo-depl configured
 - service/auth-mongo-srv configured
 - ingress.extensions/ingress-service configured
Waiting for deployments to stabilize...
 - deployment/auth-depl: waiting for rollout to finish: 1 old replicas are pending termination...
 - deployment/auth-mongo-depl: waiting for rollout to finish: 1 old replicas are pending termination...
 - deployment/auth-depl is ready. [1/2 deployment(s) still pending]
 - deployment/auth-mongo-depl is ready.
Deployments stabilized in 3.633465001s
Watching for changes...
[auth-depl-5c59699679-tnzk2 auth]
[auth-depl-5c59699679-tnzk2 auth] > auth@1.0.0 start /app
[auth-depl-5c59699679-tnzk2 auth] > nodemon ./src/index.ts
[auth-depl-5c59699679-tnzk2 auth]
[auth-depl-5c59699679-tnzk2 auth] [nodemon] 2.0.5
[auth-depl-5c59699679-tnzk2 auth] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[auth-depl-5c59699679-tnzk2 auth] [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[auth-depl-5c59699679-tnzk2 auth] [nodemon] watching extensions: ts,json
[auth-depl-5c59699679-tnzk2 auth] [nodemon] starting `ts-node ./src/index.ts`
[auth-depl-5c59699679-tnzk2 auth] (node:40) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: JWT must be defined
```

That served as a big clue, because when I went to `kubectl get secrets` I found that my JWT was no longer in the Kubernetes secret and I believe that is because my machine was inadvertently restarted recently, meaning I forgot to click on foregoing until a later time and it restarted later on that evening which restarted my local copy of Docker desktop with Kubernetes.

So I ran the `kubectl create secret...` command again and then ran `kubectl get secrets` and saw my secret key in there again.

I added back in those environment variables with the secret key or the value from that secret key inside my `auth-depl.yml` file and then ran `skaffold dev --cleanup=false` again and:

```
Listing files to watch...
 - ldco2016/auth
Generating tags...
 - ldco2016/auth -> ldco2016/auth:latest
Some taggers failed. Rerun with -vdebug for errors.
Checking cache...
 - ldco2016/auth: Found Locally
Tags used in deployment:
 - ldco2016/auth -> ldco2016/auth:367e6b2171c5c8477a3f3458d23dd73030f35716df45a290aa54baa5f4dcdaa1
Starting deploy...
 - deployment.apps/auth-depl configured
 - service/auth-srv configured
 - deployment.apps/auth-mongo-depl configured
 - service/auth-mongo-srv configured
 - ingress.extensions/ingress-service configured
Waiting for deployments to stabilize...
 - deployment/auth-depl: waiting for rollout to finish: 1 old replicas are pending termination...
 - deployment/auth-mongo-depl: waiting for rollout to finish: 1 old replicas are pending termination...
 - deployment/auth-depl is ready. [1/2 deployment(s) still pending]
 - deployment/auth-mongo-depl is ready.
Deployments stabilized in 3.612848017s
Watching for changes...
[auth-depl-5c59699679-tnzk2 auth] Error from server (BadRequest): container "auth" in pod "auth-depl-5c59699679-tnzk2" is terminated
[auth-depl-7d9bf44d9f-n9rcq auth]
[auth-depl-7d9bf44d9f-n9rcq auth] > auth@1.0.0 start /app
[auth-depl-7d9bf44d9f-n9rcq auth] > nodemon ./src/index.ts
[auth-depl-7d9bf44d9f-n9rcq auth]
[auth-depl-7d9bf44d9f-n9rcq auth] [nodemon] 2.0.5
[auth-depl-7d9bf44d9f-n9rcq auth] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[auth-depl-7d9bf44d9f-n9rcq auth] [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
WARN[0004] exit status 1
[auth-depl-7d9bf44d9f-n9rcq auth] [nodemon] watching extensions: ts,json
[auth-depl-7d9bf44d9f-n9rcq auth] [nodemon] starting `ts-node ./src/index.ts`
[auth-depl-7d9bf44d9f-n9rcq auth] Connected to MongoDB
[auth-depl-7d9bf44d9f-n9rcq auth] Listening on port 3000!!!!!
```

Back in business.

Answer (score 0):

Change all `yaml` config files similar to these changes. We must add resource limits to each `yaml` file:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: client-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1 
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: client
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: client
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: client
          image: ldco2016/client
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 512Mi
              cpu: "1"
            requests:
              memory: 256Mi
              cpu: "0.2"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-srv
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: client
  ports: 
    - name: client
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```